# Change MS-Office / Outlook dates with ECMA-Script / JavaScript

Tags: javascript, date, outlook, wsh, activexobject

Accessing Microsoft Office data via the ActiveX-Interface in the JavaScript implementation of the Windows Scripting Host, I noticed that you cannot assign a JavaScript date to an Office date variable. This will result in an error.

For example, if I want to use the following script to set the start-time of the currently selected Outlook calendar entry to "now", this does not work:

```
olApplication = new ActiveXObject( "Outlook.Application" ); // call Outlook interface
if ((olApplication.ActiveExplorer().Selection.Count > 0) && (olApplication.ActiveExplorer().Selection.Item(1).Class==26)) { // make sure an appointment-item is selected in Outlook
  now=new Date();
  olApplication.ActiveExplorer().Selection.Item(1).Start = now; /* ERROR thrown */
  olApplication.ActiveExplorer().Selection.Item(1).Save();
}
```

When I read olApplication.ActiveExplorer().Selection.Item(1).Start or any other date-field directly, it is converted into a localized String. I can easily set the date-filed by assigning it a localized time-value:

```
olApplication.ActiveExplorer().Selection.Item(1).Start = "4.5.2017 12:00:00";
```

but this will break the script in different localizations, and the format is not compatible with JavaScripts [Date.toLocaleString()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tolocalestring.asp) implementation.

How can I set dates in Office and specifically Outlook with JavaScript?

Comment: Please don't use w3schools, the statement "*…using locale conventions…*" is wrong. The value returned by *toLocaleString* is **entirely** implementation dependent, and frequently ignores user preferences in regard to language and date formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dates in Office have their own proprietary type "VarDate" (or VT_DATE), which isn't fully compatible with the JavaScript Date-type.
The brief documentation can be found here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff520995(v=vs.85).aspx

VarDate variables can be confusing because some things that are familiar from JavaScript-dates work with them as well. Hence, you can compare VarDates much in the same way as JavaScript dates.

For example, you can compare the starting time of two selected Outlook-Appointments as follows (assuming here and below you've initiated the ActiveX-interface as in your example in the question):

```
if (olApplication.ActiveExplorer().Selection.Item(1).Start > olApplication.ActiveExplorer().Selection.Item(2).Start) ...
```

However, if you want to introduce a date you created and manipulated in JavaScript, you need to explicitly convert it to the VarData-type.

Luckily, Microsoft covers this case with their ECMA-Script implementation of the Date object: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/scripting/javascript/reference/date-object-javascript

So you can convert a Date-variable to a VarDate-variable with the [getVarDate-Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/scripting/javascript/reference/getvardate-method-date-javascript) of the Date object. This allows you to change the starting time of the selected Outlook-appointment like this:

```
var now = new Date();
olApplication.ActiveExplorer().Selection.Item(1).Start = now.getVarDate();
```

Finally, you can also manipulate VarDate-variables with the full range of JavaScript's Date-functions by converting it to a Date-object. Microsoft's Date-constructor accepts a VarDate variable as a possible parameter:

```
var outlookAppointmentStartTime = new Date(olApplication.ActiveExplorer().Selection.Item(1).Start);
```

Comment: "Date" is not a [*type*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-ecmascript-language-types) in ECMAScript, it's a built-in object. ;-)